# Checking Gradients with Scipy

Tags: python, math, scipy, gradient

I want to use [`scipy.optimize.check_grad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html) to check the gradient of my implementation of the [sigmoid function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html); here's my Python function:

```
def sigmoid(x, gradient=False):
    y = 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-x))
    return numpy.multiply(y, 1 - y) if gradient else y
```

Here are the arguments and the call to `check_grad`:

```
x0 = numpy.random.uniform(-30, 30, (4, 5))
func = sigmoid
grad = lambda x: sigmoid(x, gradient=True)
error = scipy.optimize.check_grad(func, grad, x0)
```

I get the error below. The shape mismatch refers to the operation `xk+d`. Any idea what could be causing this?

> File "scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 597, in approx_fprime
>      grad[k] = (f(*((xk+d,)+args)) - f0) / d[k]
>   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,5) (4)

Comment: As noted below, it's because to check the gradient you have to iterate over every single element of your matrix and +/- some epsilon in order to calculate the derivative (using the standard equation). Scipy could flatten your matrix out for you. However, it should be easy enough to pass in a flattened version yourself with `M.flatten()`. In Matlab you would just do `M(:)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because `check_gradient` only accepts flat arrays of points. It should work if you used an array `x0` of shape `(20,)` instead of `(4, 5)`. But it does not!

Here's the implementation of `approx_fprime` in my installation (`scipy.__version__ = '0.9.0'`):

```
def approx_fprime(xk,f,epsilon,*args):
    f0 = f(*((xk,)+args))
    grad = numpy.zeros((len(xk),), float)
    ei = numpy.zeros((len(xk),), float)
    for k in range(len(xk)):
        ei[k] = epsilon
        grad[k] = (f(*((xk+ei,)+args)) - f0)/epsilon
        ei[k] = 0.0
    return grad
```

I have looked through it several times, finding it hard to believe that such atrocious code could be inside the scipy distribution, convinced I must be missing something... But I am afraid it is just wrong. If you replace it with:

```
def approx_fprime(xk,f,epsilon,*args):
    return (f(*((xk + epsilon,) + args)) - f(*((xk,) + args))) / epsilon
```

It now works for me. With `x0.shape = (20,)` I get:

```
In [2]: error
Out[2]: 1.746097524556073e-08
```

And with `x0.shape = (4, 5)`:

```
In [4]: error
Out[4]: 
array([  1.03560895e-08,   1.45994321e-08,   8.54143390e-09,
         1.09225833e-08,   9.85988655e-09])
```

So it seems it is really not ready for non-flat arrays at other places too. But the implementation is very broken either way: you should file a bug report.

Comment: That way of approximating the gradient does not work, though. You should increment each argument by `eps` one at a time. For example when `f` maps arrays to scalars: the gradient should be an array, but `(f(x+eps) - f(x)) / eps` will produce a scalar.

Comment: @PaulManta I see, it wasn't so wrong after all, that was the catch... It still seems to me like a pretty useless function. I think the way it is set up it only works with functions that convert vectors into scalars, and then `x0` must be a single vector, not a bunch of them. In your case you can get your call to work if `x0.shape = (1,)`, i.e. if you give it a length-1 vector, it won't work with a scalar. As far as I can tell, that's about as good as it being broken!

Comment: Yes, `check_grad` isn't useful in that many cases, unfortunately. Well, the algorithm is simple to implement so it shouldn't be that big of a problem.

Comment: to see & check visually the grad can calculate [like here](https://www.tomasbeuzen.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/chapters/appendixC_computing-derivatives.html)- with the bigger qty (e.g. n=1000) stepwise division, to have smaller sized steps dx

Answer (score 0):

about your code (need *Vectorization* - if you do need - do *flatten()* or *ravel()*):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def sigmoid_obj(x, gradient=False):
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1*x))
    res= np.multiply(y, 1 - y) if gradient else y
    return sum(res)  # must return scalar !

def num_gradient(x):
    return optimize.approx_fprime(x, sigmoid_obj, eps)

x = np.array(np.random.uniform(-30, 30, (4, 5)))     # shape(4,5)
##x0= [0,]        # guess !! var(s) used in objective_func

eps = np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)

error = optimize.check_grad(sigmoid_obj, num_gradient, x.flatten() )
print(error)
```

But usually, `objective_func` is for only **one** `x_point` projection to `y_target`, starting to optimize from `x0=guess`. In the simplest version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def sigmoid_obj(x, gradient=False):
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1*x))
    res= np.multiply(y, 1 - y) if gradient else y
    return res

def num_gradient(x):
    return optimize.approx_fprime(x, sigmoid_obj, eps)

x = np.array(np.random.uniform(-30, 30, (4, 5)))
x0= [0,]        # guess !! init_var(s) used in objective_func

eps = np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)

error = optimize.check_grad(sigmoid_obj, num_gradient, x0 )
print(error)
```

? if your initial_guess is assumed to be only one x, thus `guess=x0` must be `[0,]`

P.S. `optimize.check_grad()` internally uses `optimize.approx_fprime()`, the latest is calculated as of one point projection to y [as is Locally]... OR can calculate it analitically (with SymPy  or manually, as in docs' example):
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

```
def func(x):
    return x[0]**2 - 0.5 * x[1]**3
def grad(x):
    return [2 * x[0], -1.5 * x[1]**2]   # here can be numerical_gradient=optimize.approx_fprime(...)
from scipy.optimize import check_grad
print(check_grad(func, grad, x0= [1.5, -1.5]))
```